# Extracting author names from tex file in R

Tags: r, string, latex

I would like to extract all the references cited in a tex file. Below an example:

```
cat("...", "Some author \\cite{xxx}", "Other author \\cite{yyy}, more text \\cite{zzz}",
        "...}", file = "tex", sep="\n")
tex <- readLines("tex")
```

The expected output would be:

```
refs <- c("xxx","yyy","zzz")
```

I ventured in grep without any success. Therefore, I would be glad to receive suggestions here.

Answer (score 2):

You can firstly check each line to see if it contains `cite`, and then extract the author from cite using `sub` and back reference:

```
hasCite <- grepl("\\\\cite", tex)
sub(".*\\\\cite\\{(.*?)\\}.*", "\\1", tex[hasCite])
# [1] "xxx" "yay"
```

*Update*:

If you have multiple matches in the string, you could use `stringr::str_extract_all`; Here use *regex* look around `(?<=...)` (look behind) and `(?=)` (look ahead) to restrict the pattern so that contents surrounded by `\\cite{}` are extracted:

```
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(tex, "(?<=\\\\cite\\{)(.*?)(?=\\})"))
# [1] "xxx" "yyy" "zzz"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and you actually resolved my example. However, my own fault, your solution does not capture TeX lines with more than one reference. I have adapted my example and further suggestions on it would be greatly appreciated.